# Add pem certificate to truststore programmatically

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, resttemplate, truststore

One of the public API I'm using forgot to provide the certificate of the intermediary issuing authority when renewing its certificate resulting in PKIX exception for my app (`PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`).. I want to add the server API certificate that I downloaded to the truststore so that my Springboot application can access the API.

Following the doc I tried to add the certificate une sing SSL bundles.

```
@Bean
protected RestTemplate createRestTemplateClient(@Autowired RestTemplateBuilder restBuilder,SslBundles sslBundles ) {
    restBuilder.setSslBundle(sslBundles.getBundle("scanr")).build();
    return restBuilder.build();
}
```

With the following `application.properties` and `scanr.pem` in the `resources` folder

```
spring.ssl.bundle.pem.scanr.truststore.certificate=classpath:scanr.pem
```

He same PKIX exception is still thrown. Am I missing something?